# Shape hyperlink to the next empty cell in column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a button (kind of) in Excel by clicking on which user can get to the next empty cell in the column B to enter the date.

I have seen this functionality on many spreadsheets, but I cannot recreate it for some reason.
None of those spreadsheets I have seen use macros, I also prefer not to use macros in mine.

I know how to create a simple hyperlink formula, but I do not know how to create hyperlink on the shape that will have the same functionality as formula.

Any help or suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: any reason for not using macro? because it is very easy with macro, either button or shape.

Comment: I know it is, but would prefer not to use it at all

Comment: Do you know the next empty cell ahead of time? Will it change location?

Comment: The cell is always in the same column, lets say column B where I have dates, so that when user has to enter something new he/she has to simply click the button to get to the next empty cell in that column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Follow these steps in order one by one and you will get it right**
or just simply download the sheet below to save time.
***Here it is all:***
Actually, you need to find the row number of the first empty cell:
using this formula, `=MATCH(TRUE;INDEX(B1:B13="";0);0)` which I put in my **K2**

 
***TRICK*** then first you create a name (say *GoToEmptyCell*) in the *name manager* refering to any other empty cell except **K2**, for example i pointed to **J2**,
 then, you create your shape and assign a hyperlink (see the image below), click on *place in this document* and down in the list you see your *name* (*GoToEmptyCell*), choose this and then press OK. 
 **NOW** go back to the *name manager* and modify the reference for this *name* and put this formula there (in the **refers to** box ) instead of **J2**

```
=INDIRECT("B"&hyperlink!$K$2)
```

[image]
So now *trick* is done. Click on the shape and it goes to the empty cell. Right, tell me if it doesn't work.
Here is the example sheet [in this file downloadable from this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rvrrayjzwt0ud5b/hyperlink.xlsx?dl=0)

***P.S.*** follow the order of the operations please. And remember to adjust the formula to your ***regional settings*** by ***replacing the ";" with ","*** . Have fun.

Comment: @AHC the following part is not very clear, can you please expand on this.

Comment: which part do you mean? @AlexB

Comment: then, you create your shape and assign a hyperlink, click on place in this document and down in the list you see your name (GoToEmptyCell), choose this and then press OK.

Comment: I have created the shape, but what do I need to assign as the hyperlink the named range that I have created?

Comment: Sorry all clear now, I was making a huge mistake here

Comment: i added an image, tell me if it helps. if not, i will try again.

Comment: it surely does, but I managed to figure it all out as I was pointing to the wrong cell when I was placing the formula to replace the value of the named range

Comment: Can you do this with named ranges?

Answer (score 2):

Pick a cell that you want to use as a "button" and enter this formula:

```
=HYPERLINK("#B" & MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISBLANK(B:B),0,0),0),"First Empty")
```

Clicking on it will take you to the first empty cell in column **B**

**EDIT#1:**

To do this with a *Shape,* assign the following macro to that *Shape*

```
Sub FirstEmpty()
    For Each r In Range("B:B")
        If r.Value = "" Then
            r.Select
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT#2**

It might be possible to :

- create a formula giving the *address* for the first empty in column **B**
- create a *Defined Name* using that formula
- assign a hyperlink to the Shape based on that *Defined Name*

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I need as I have mentioned in my question, I know how to use formula to do it, but I need to have the same on the shape instead of the button.

Comment: OK Thanks, but I am trying to avoid macros

Comment: Perhaps another poster will help us.

Comment: I should hope so, I have seen it in several spreadsheets that do not use macros, when I did check the hyperlink on the shape it points to the same sheet that the button is on and in the address it is always A1, but somehow it points to the next empty cell in column B, always

Comment: @AlexB I give a possible approach in my **EDIT#2,** but I don't know the details..........Good Luck!

Comment: @AlexB I provided the detailed explanation how to do this. refer to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27132822/4230650).

Answer (score 0):

Simpler version I got to work:

First, make sure the worksheet you want to link to does not have spaces in the name. Underscores and Dashes will work though.

This one is for data in Column `"A"` but it can be any column (or Row in theory).

```
=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE("#Historical_Data!$A",SUM(COUNTA(Historical_Data!$A$1:$A$365)-14)),"Link to the xxxxxxx")
```

Breakdown:
`[=HYPERLINK(CONCATENATE(]` - Sets up a way to dynamically specify the link address using Concatenate.

`["#Historical_Data!$A",]` - "#" is required as the first character to identify that the link is in the same workbook. `"Historical_Data"` is the name of the tab/worksheet I linked to. `"!$A"` is the column ID I want the link to take me to.

`[SUM(COUNTA(Historical_Data!$A$1:$A$366)-14)),]` - Dynamically specifies the `Row#` that will be added to the end of the Link address above. I used the `"SUM(COUTNA()-#"` combination in this specific instance to make the last 14 rows of data show up when I click the link. You can put `"+1"` instead of `"-14"` to put the cursor on the first blank cell. The data range of `"Historical_Data!$A$1:$A$366"` was sufficient for me because my table will never have more than 365 days of data; works just as well with `$A:$A` as the range.

`["Link to the xxxxxxx")]`- Text that will display in the Hyperlinked Cell.